# How to access IBOutlet from one class to other class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to access the IBOutlet from my class ViewController in class SecTableCell.
But it is showing the next error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
class A: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet  var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
}
```

So, here I want to access datePicker in other class B

```
 class B:UITableViewCell{

    var obj=A()

    @IBAction func datePickerAction(_ sender: Any) {
        obj.datePicker.isHidden=false
    }
 }
```

Please tell what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: If data picker in your cell then you should set the outlet into your UITableViewCell class

Comment: But it is not on the cell, it is on the top view which I have to connect through viewcontroller and datepicker will be shown when the button is clicked on a particular cell.

Comment: show the data picker in your didSelectRowAtindexPath delegate method

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have created a new instance of `A`(`UIViewController`) with this line.

```
var obj=A()
```

This initializer does not loads the instance from the Interface builder.
Hence the `IBOutlets` of A here are `nil`, i.e. `datePicker` is `nil`.

When there is action on button, `B`'s `datePickerAction` is called where `A` exists but it does not have `datePricer` loaded(i.e. its nil here), hence the crash.

To solve your problem you need to inject or say feed in your A (i.e. `self` here) in cell as

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //...
    cell.obj = self //Injection
    //...
}
```

And B would then be modified to accept `obj` of type `A` `optional`

```
class B:UITableViewCell{

  var obj: A?
  @IBAction func datePickerAction(_ sender: Any) {
      obj?.datePicker.isHidden=false

    }
 }
```

Comment: I am not able to access obj in cellForRowAt.

Comment: Please show how your tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) looks like